# Where can I SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY in my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, deadlock

I am unsure as to where I can use the

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY...
```

command in my stored procedure. Does it need to be before I begin a transaction? Or can it be anywhere in the transaction?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question: you can change the priority wherever you need to. If you're unsure then you can just put it at the start of the procedure, unless perhaps it's a very long procedure and there's only one specific query that is prone to deadlocks.

Although a better solution would probably be to [avoid the deadlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if possible.

You may also want to note that any priority change inside a stored procedure is reset to the priority of the calling session when the procedure exits:

```
set deadlock_priority high
go
select deadlock_priority from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@spid
go

create proc dbo.p 
as
begin
select deadlock_priority as 'PriorityBefore' from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@spid 
set deadlock_priority low
select deadlock_priority as 'PriorityAfter' from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@spid 
end
go

exec dbo.p

select deadlock_priority from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@spid

drop proc dbo.p
go

set deadlock_priority normal
go
```